# What are the differences between indoor, outdoor, and indoor/outdoor basketballs?

Tags: equipment, basketball

At times, when I play basketball, I notice some basektballs are labeled as "indoor", "[outdoor](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Spalding-Official-NBA-Youth-Outdoor-Basketball-27.5/11032308)", or "[indoor/outdoor](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Spalding-NBA-Official-Indoor-Outdoor-Basketball/2416205)".

**What are the differences between indoor, outdoor, and indoor/outdoor basketballs?** Is it a design/material difference? I assume outdoor basketballs are designed with durability in mind, but is there a need for the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the differences between indoor, outdoor, and indoor/outdoor
>   basketballs?

**"Indoor" Basketballs**

- Made of full-grain leather
- Requires being broken-in for optimal use
- Feels smooth and has superior grip
- Reliable/consistent bounce characteristics
- [Expensive](http://store.nba.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2674368&CAWELAID=1018762924&cagpspn=pla) - due to cost of materials

**"All-Surface" Basketballs**

- Made of rubber or synthetic leather
- Can be used right out of the box
- Feels rough and has less than superior grip
- Does not have as reliable/consistent bounce characteristics
- Not as expensive

> Is it a design/material difference?

Yes. Full-grain leather vs. rubber/synthetic leather.

> Is there a need for the difference [between "indoor" and "all-surface" basketballs]?

Yes. Basketballs are made specifically indoor use or all-surface (outdoor, indoor/outdoor) use.  <sub>([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball_%28ball%29)) ([2](http://www.livestrong.com/article/135835-what-is-difference-between-outdoor-basketball-indoor-basketball/))</sub>

Indoor basketballs, when exposed to outdoor elements such as asphalt, dirt, and moisture, wear out sooner than all-surface basketballs.

Using indoor basketballs indoors and all-surface basketballs indoors or outdoors will maximize the life of each type of basketball. The cost to replace an indoor basketball is more than the cost to replace an all-surface basketball.

Comment: "Requires being broken-in for optimal use" ... What does this mean?

Comment: [Play with it on the court](http://www.livestrong.com/article/426659-how-to-soften-a-genuine-leather-basketball/).